# Strange ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on some devices while drawing polylines

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

Below is the code that I am using to draw routes. Whenever the user pauses the workout I want to show this path as pink polyline. I therefore made my own interface named `MapHelper` and taken one boolean as `isPause` and `lastPause`. When the user saves his/her workout I save all route points as array and on typical list I am displaying this maps as feeds and for that I am using lite mode version of Googlemap.
Below is my adapter class

**Adapter.java**

```
public class FeedsAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedsAdpter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private FeedsFragment feedsFragment;
    RoundedTransFormation transFormation;
    private ArrayList<FeedsDto> allFeedsList = new ArrayList<FeedsDto>();


    public FeedsAdpter(Context context, FeedsFragment feedsFragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedsFragment = feedsFragment;
        transFormation=new RoundedTransFormation(3, 15,Color.WHITE);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_feeds, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        if(Validator.isNotNull(holder.mapView.getMap())) {
            GoogleMap googleMap = holder.mapView.getMap();
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        }
        Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(holder.userImg);
        holder.userImg.setImageDrawable(null);
        holder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(null);
        holder.tvPost.setOnClickListener(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final FeedsDto feeds = allFeedsList.get(position);
        if (Validator.isNotNull(feeds)) {


            if (Validator.isNotNull(feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryMap()) && feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryMap().length > 0) {
                if (holder.mapView != null) {
                    holder.mapView.onCreate(null);
                    holder.mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            if (Validator.isNotNull(googleMap)) {
                                googleMap.clear();
                                holder.mapView.setClickable(false);
                                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
                                List<HistoryMap> historyMaps = new ArrayList<HistoryMap>();
                                historyMaps.addAll(Arrays.asList(feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryMap()));
                                Util.drawRouteIntoMap(historyMaps, googleMap);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                holder.mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        feedsFragment=null;
        if(Validator.isNotNull(allFeedsList)){
            allFeedsList.clear();
        }
        InputMethodManager methodManager = (InputMethodManager)context. getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        try {
            Field mNextServedView = methodManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mNextServedView");
            mNextServedView.setAccessible(true);
            mNextServedView.set(methodManager, null);

            Field mServedView = methodManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mServedView");
            mServedView.setAccessible(true);
            mServedView.set(methodManager, null);

            Method method = methodManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("finishInputLocked");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(methodManager);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static void hideKeyboard(Context context) {

        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            View view = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addAll(List<FeedsDto> list) {
        allFeedsList.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        allFeedsList = new ArrayList<FeedsDto>();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allFeedsList.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.img_user_pic)
        ImageView userImg;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_user_name)
        TextView tvUserName;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_duration)
        TextView tvDuration;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_msg)
        TextView tvMsg;
        @Bind(R.id.workout_map_summary)
        MapView mapView;
        @Bind(R.id.et_feeds_comment)
        EditText etComment;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_post)
        ImageView tvPost;
        @Bind(R.id.img_like_btn)
        ImageButton likeBtn;
        @Bind(R.id.img_comment_btn)
        ImageButton commentBtn;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_like_count)
        TextView tvLikecount;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_comment_count)
        TextView tvCommentcount;
        @Bind(R.id.feeds_parent)
        LinearLayout feedsParent;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

    }
}
```

[Here is the link to json file that I'm receving](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1jXkMMNkEv9amZvMHVnOGo0bGc) 
[Here is the link to model class that is required](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1jXkMMNkEv9SVFtUGFzLVoyUDA)
 While drawing polylines it is throwing *arrayindexoutofbound* exception only in lenovo k5 among the devices I did testing on. I already asked this question on [ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on Android polyline draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261244/arrayindexoutofbounds-on-android-polyline-draw/39386840?noredirect=1#comment66291048_39386840)

Comment: It may possible google map is not ready for draw polyline. I am not sure but possibility.

Comment: @ Ankita Shah how can i determine map is ready or not as i already using mapready callback

Comment: Is this class depending on any other class? Can I run it in as a standalone?

Comment: @ Flame_Phoenix i forget to upload java class file i will update the link

Comment: @ Flame_phoenix i updated question

Comment: I like to believe I am a man of my word. Since I am lost in the darkness of doubt surrounding this question, perhaps it is time to create a new beacon of light for others to see. Started a Bounty!

Comment: @ Flame_phoenix thank you so much for your efforts

Comment: Just trying to help ;P

Comment: There is already a very similar [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9969) reported on the Google Maps API issue tracker that sounds a lot like yours. The engineering team has already acknowledged it, but please star it!

Comment: @VilleN.thank you so much for giving link. i starred it and also posted my exception there.